# Locked out of ssh after mounting bind /dev /run /proc and reboot

Tags: filesystems, kernel, mount, lfs

**I've added the following commands in my /etc/rc.local file to automatically mount kernel's virtual file system, as said on Linux From Scratch (LFS).

And rebooted...**

> **Sections**
>   6.2.2 Mounting and Populating /dev
>   6.2.3. Mounting Virtual Kernel File Systems

```
mount -v --bind /dev $LFS/dev
mount -vt devpts devpts $LFS/dev/pts -o gid=5,mode=620
mount -vt proc proc $LFS/proc
mount -vt sysfs sysfs $LFS/sys
mount -vt tmpfs tmpfs $LFS/run

if [ -h $LFS/dev/shm ]; then
  mkdir -pv $LFS/$(readlink $LFS/dev/shm
fi
```

**Now this is what I get when trying to SSH bakk in:**

```
ssh -vvv -i lfs.pem ubuntu@52.21.192.61   

OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016   
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/heitor/.ssh/config   
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config   
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *   
debug2: resolving "52.22.192.60" port 22   
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0   
debug1: Connecting to 52.22.192.60 [52.22.192.60] port 22.   
debug1: Connection established.   
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory   
debug1: identity file dev/heitor/linux-from-scratch/lfs-ssh-rescue.pem type -1   
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory   
debug1: identity file dev/heitor/linux-from-scratch/lfs-ssh-rescue.pem-cert type -1   
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0   
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1   
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `$LFS` set anywhere before that? Otherwise you're bind-mounting `/dev` onto itself, which won't end well…

Comment: And you're building a Linux from scratch on an Amazon cloud server? That doesn't sound like the most convenient testing environment… How about a virtual machine on your local box? ;)

Comment: No, it is not set. I'm gonna have to mount the volume in another instance and fix the script. Right?

Comment: Let's back off a little. What's the problem you are trying to solve? You shouldn't normally need to do any kind of mounting yourself on a normal Linux distro, and it might be a little early to try building a "Linux From Scratch". ;)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is SSH back into my instance. Normally Udev mounts things for you, but LFS doesn't have Udev, so I have to mount everything myself.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it mounting the volume in another instance, removing the broken commands and mounting it back in my Linux From scratch instance. 
Now I can ssh back in it normally =)

Thanks for the help everyone!